# Sublime text 3 using pip to download stuff

Tags: python-3.x, pip, sublimetext3

I have set my sublime text to build on python version 3.4.3. I am trying to download `Scrapy` to test some stuff, but `pip` download is failing.

My code in sublime text is :

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
pip install Scrapy
```

Output:

```
File "/Users/X/Documents/Learn/XX/Python1.py", line 3
    pip install Scrapy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `pip install scrapy` from the command line, not from within a Python program. Open up Terminal (**`Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal.app`**) and run `pip` from there.